# How to create Dynamic Widgets in custom function and call them in viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, objective-c

as i am new to iOS Developing, i was wondering how should i create a custom method to create a TextField or a button because if i place all the dynamic widget in `viewdidLoad` method, it becomes so huge and also not a good practice to place whole code in one functions.

Here is my `viewDidLoad` method

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewdidLoad];
self.textFiled = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(10.0f,30.0f,3000.0f,30.0f)];
self.textField.delegate = self;
self.textField.borderStyle = UItextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
[self.view addSubView:self.textField];
}
```

and many more dynamic widgets like this in this method. Now i tried to create a custom function to create a Dynamic TextField and call it here in `viewdidLoad`

```
-(TextField)createDynamicTextField :(TextField *) textField{
//Do Something Here
}
```

I am at a loss as what should i do after here.

Please tell me how should i create dynamic TextField  in this custom UITextField type method and call it in viewDidLoad. As it is a UITextField type function , i will return the textfield and store in the global textfield i created above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do this:

```
- (UITextField *)createDynamicTextField
{
    UITextField *tempTF = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f,30.0f,3000.0f,30.0f)];
    tempTF.delegate = self;
    tempTF.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    return tempTF;
}
```

and then in your viewDidLoad:

```
self.textField = [self createDynamicTextField];
[self.view addSubview:self.textField];
```

or you could even subclass UITextField if they will all be the same size and create a new method called:

```
- (UITextField *)initCustomFieldWithDelegate:(id<UITextFieldDelegate>)delegate
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f,30.0f,3000.0f,30.0f)];
    if (self) {
        self.delegate = delegate;
        self.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    }
    return self;
}
```

then you won't need any of that code in your class.

Answer (score 0):

```
it becomes so huge and also not a good practice to place whole code in one functions.
```

So then divide it in small functions, one for adding the button, one for adding the textfield....

Honestly, you cannot stop adding things in the viewDidLoad just because the code is long.

In this custom method, just add the view:

```
-(TextField)createDynamicTextField :(TextField *) textField{
self.textFiled = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(10.0f,30.0f,3000.0f,30.0f)];
self.textField.delegate = self;
self.textField.borderStyle = UItextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
[self.view addSubView:self.textField];
}
```

Comment: I did this, and so i did it for a button and a label, and called them in viewDidLoad. The View didn't formed

Comment: I have edited my question. Please read the last paragraph. That is what i exactly require